# SciPy - Delaunay for creating a simple graph of geographic points with latitude and longitude

Tags: python, scipy, coordinates, geospatial, delaunay

I have a dataset of Points of Interest (via latitude/longitude) and want to generate a graph out of them. The aim is to have a routeable graph. So I want to have the "nearest" POIs to be connected via an edge.

I came up with [Delaunay](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html), cause this will create a simple planar graph out of the points. As far as good, i got some results. But the problem is, the edges are not good connected, due to the fact that the earth is not flat. In the northern and southern hemisphere the triangles are vertically strechted.

Is there a way to use the scipy.spatial.Delaunay package in order to accept latitude / longitude as positioning information, instead having a flat area?
Or does it make sense to use another procedure? Would be great to have some solutionen for python.

Comment: Is your set of points covering the whole world ?

Comment: Actual not - but the data set is growing and its possible to have it spread over the world. The points are only on terrestrial area. So more than 70 % of the earth will be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it running. I read this [article](https://www.redblobgames.com/x/1842-delaunay-voronoi-sphere/) and did the first steps to create the delaunay. 
The main point is to make a stereographic projection and afterwards the regular 2D delaunay triangulation.

Now i got a nice basic graph.
[image]